# Calculate a error coefficient to be applied to future measures

Tags: regression, estimation, modeling, error, calibration

I have these data:

```
X <- c(0.7100, 0.0310, 0.0000, 0.0474, 0.3640, 0.0590, 
   0.8236, 0.0000, 0.0025, 0.2430, 0.0283, 0.2710, 
   0.3754, 0.7500, 0.0490, 0.0000, 0.7388, 0.0000, 
   0.0320, 0.7585, 0.0000, 0.8320, 0.9040, 0.0000, 
   0.0700, 0.0000, 0.7115, 0.9904, 0.6250, 0.5073, 
   0.8014, 0.6440, 0.0000, 0.0630, 0.2382, 0.6900, 
   0.3620, 0.0070, 0.2090, 0.3501)

Y <- c(0.6660, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0560, 0.4130, 0.2700, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.4280, 
 0.0652, 0.3260, 0.3366, 0.9380, 0.0490, 0.0700, 0.7837, 0.000, 0.0220, 0.7210,
 0.0223, 1.00, 0.9910, 0.00, 0.1890, 0.000, 0.8684, 0.9852, 0.5070, 0.6241,
 0.7254, 0.710, 0.000, 0.0370, 0.3381, 0.6920, 0.242, 0.000, 0.02, 0.2236)

Y2 <- c(0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0090, 0.904, 0.3400, 0.9980, 0.1710, 0.8260, 0.1042, 0.0156,
    0.7230, 0.7570, 0.6200, 0.277, 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.6470, 0.0140, 0.0000, 1.0000,
    0.5640, 0.3970, 0.0090, 0.000, 0.9684, 0.0099, 0.0000, 0.5380, 0.1560, 0.0000,
    0.0153, 0.6470, 0.2450, 0.018, 0.0000, 0.3250, 1.0000, 0.1360, 1.0000, 0.9815,
    0.0064, 0.0000, 0.1890, 0.057, 0.4110, 0.5320, 0.5113, 1.0000, 0.6660, 0.0290,
    0.6840, 0.9960, 0.3580, 0.548, 0.9980, 0.9680, 0.0000, 0.8501, 0.0750, 0.0380,
    0.6047, 0.1000, 0.8648, 0.049, 0.0050, 0.1840, 0.4480, 0.2180, 0.8150, 0.3720,
    0.0720, 0.0566, 0.6080, 1.000, 0.3195, 0.0017, 0.4180, 0.0000, 0.7190, 0.5190)
```

All these are area measurements. X is the area measured in the field that is my "true" reference. 
Y is the measured area through an instrument.

First, I want to find the error between X and Y to get a correction parameter.

Than I want to use the same correction parameters to correct future measures. In the example these future measures are represented by Y2.

I tried using the RMSE from the regression line, but it was not really satisfactory then I tried following the suggestion from this: [Determining a correction factor and applying it to a second set of numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/determining-a-correction-factor-and-applying-it-to-a-second-set-of-numbers#)

which look very promising. 
But, I am stuck at the use of the correction factor to further data without a field comparison. 
Also because I will be using it on samples with different sample size.

I would appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: Could you describe how the area was measured?  The data indicate it would be advantageous to model $\sqrt{Y}$ as a function of $\sqrt{X},$ which is suggestive of a measurement process involving multiplication of two other measurements.  (An even better model indicated by the data is to examine the association of $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ where $f$ is a standardized "folded root" function $f(p) = (1 + \sqrt{p} - \sqrt{1-p})/2.$)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the area represents forest patches, X is by drones, Y is by satellite remote sensing. Due to the significantly higher resolution of drones we conisider it to be the best estimate, while we know that satellite have intrinsic errors caused by pixel resolution.

Comment: Can you please add this new info in comments to the post as an edit? Not everybody reads comments.